# What will happen to balloon if it is filled with water and kept inside container containing water? Consider balloon at middle of container

Tags: pressure, water, fluid-statics

Consider water-filled balloon kept initially at mid-height of container. Will it lift or sink or stay there? Will balloon shrink or stay as it is? (Assume balloon material is elastic. Pressure above container water is atmospheric. Note that temperature of water outside and inside balloon is same.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the density of the balloon material is less than water (the density of latex rubber is slightly less than water), it would theoretically rise because the density of the volume of the combination of the material and enclosed water is less than the density of water alone.

However, the degree to which it rises may be imperceptible since the density of the balloon plus water would only be slightly less than water. Any turbulence of the surrounding water could mask its upward movement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If we consider balloon material desity same as that of water density OR consider negligible balloon material density, then what will be the scenario? I am thinking it like surrounding pressure is higher so balloon get compressed (Volume decreases) till water inside balloon gets pressurised to pressure equal to surrounding pressure. New density of water ρ' (+balloon material ρ) is higher than density of water in container. So balloon will move down till outer water's density equal to ρ'. Here container water also. compressible so it's density increase along depth.

Comment: It will float submerged without rising or sinking. The surrounding water pressure is the same as the pressure of the water contained in the balloon.  If the density of an object is less than water it will float partially submerged. If equal to water it will float completely submerged. If greater than water it will sink. The upward buoyant force equals the weight of the volume of water displaced by the object.

Answer (score 0):

We need to compare $$V_\text{balloon, interior}\rho_\text{water, interior}+V_\text{balloon, skin}\rho_\text{skin material},\tag{1}$$

the mass associated with the balloon and its contents, with

$$(V_\text{balloon, interior}+V_\text{balloon, skin})\rho_\text{water, free},\tag{2}$$

the mass associated with the displaced water. Note that

$$\rho_\text{water, interior}=\rho_\text{water, free}+\Delta\rho_\text{water, pressurization}$$ because the water is pressurized by the stretched balloon skin; the difference scales up with water’s [compressibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressibility) $\kappa$ (i.e., the reciprocal of the [bulk modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulk_modulus)). Specifically, $$\Delta \rho_\text{water, pressurization}=\int d\left(\frac{m_\text{water, interior}}{V_\text{balloon, interior}}\right)=-m\int d\left(\frac{1}{V^2_\text{balloon, interior}}\right)=m\int\frac{\kappa}{V}dP.$$

Various lines of reasoning on the page as it stands rely on one or more of these factors being negligible, so that the two masses being compared are essentially equal.  Specifically, considering these effects, the balloon balances when we have at least one of

- The skin material has a density similar to that of water, or
- The skin volume is negligible,

and at least one of

- The compressibility of water is essentially zero, or
- The pressure applied by the skin material is negligible.

Comment: So basically two scenarios are there Case 1) Water is incompressible - Water balloon with density ρ and pressure p(atm) get surrounded by water of density ρ and pressure [patm +ρg(h/2)]. Will balloon burst in this case? Since we are assuming negligible effect of balloon material. Buoyant force is equal to weight of water displaced + Weight of liquid column above. Is this how force will get balanced? so net force on balloon will become zero. Why would balloon move up or down? Case 2) Water is compressible - Such balloon will shrink but still confused about up or down movement? (Ignore material)

Comment: I don't see why the balloon would burst. Hydrostatic (i.e., equitriaxial) pressure can't really damage uniform or flexible materials. (Submarine hulls, for example, can implode precisely because they're **not** in an equitriaxial stress state; the [hoop stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_stress) is far higher than the surrounding pressure.)

Comment: To check whether the balloon will move up (down), check whether line (1) is smaller (larger) than line (2) above.